# numpy array - more and less than

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison, valueerror

i have a numpy array:(for example:)

```
>>> pixels
array([[233, 233, 233],
       [245, 245, 245],
       [251, 251, 251],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248]], dtype=uint8)
```

what can i do to get a boolean array for the values that great than 230 and lower than 240 (for example)?
when i write

```
230<pixels<240
```

i get this massage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    100<pixels<300
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

it is also does not work if i write

```
230<pixels and 240>pixels
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Use parenthesis and `&` operator.

Comment: Just do `(pixels > 230) & (pixels < 240)`, as suggested by @Divakar

Answer (score 4):

With `numpy.where` routine:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[233, 233, 233],
       [245, 245, 245],
       [251, 251, 251],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248],
       [248, 248, 248]], dtype='uint8')

b = np.where((a > 230) & (a < 240), True, False)
print(b)
```

The output:

```
[[ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
```